# Ошибка импорта глобального CSS в стандартном приложении Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, nextjs, server-side-rendering

В начальном приложении Next.js (которое автоматически создается при использовании "npx create-next-app") возникает ошибка импорта CSS:
[image: скриншот ошибки]
Забавно то, что приложение просит перенести импорт глобальных стилей из `pages\_app.js` в `pages/_app.js`.

Полагаю, что дело в обратной косой черте в пути файла, но понятия не имею, как это исправить.

Comment: в каком терминале ты звпускаешь?

Comment: Windows PowerShell в VS Code

Comment: попробуй в cmd простом

Comment: проблема осталась

Comment: в какой именно момент появляется ошибка?

Comment: вот скриншот всех сообщений: https://imgur.com/a/rxXzWYG

Comment: не получается воспроизвести. Эта ошибка при любом созданном `npx create-next-app`?

Comment: да, в трех случаях из трех. На Ubuntu все работает нормально.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130302/discussion-between-grundy-and--).